# regex for getting html starting tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I want get only the starting html tags. Lets say I have html like this

```
<div class="some">Here is a sample text<br /><p>A paragraph here</p></div>
<ul><li>List Item</li></ul>
```

From the above html I want to extract this information

```
<div
<br
<p
<ul
<li
```

see I dont need ending '>' of tags

Comment: I suck at regex, so whenever there's a simple regex expression I need, I use this site to help me construct it. I figured out the answer to your question in 10 seconds even though I only know the basics: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try regex `/<[a-zA-Z]+[1-6]?/g`. I added the `[1-6]` for the header HTML tags - I think they're the only ones with numbers. If you wanted to be sure you could do `/<[a-zA-Z0-9]+/g`, since in HTML a `<` is always a tag (unless it's a comment `<--`), because in-line `<` get converted to `&lt;`.

Answer (score 1):

The following returns you an array of the matches with what you want from the html body.

```
'<div class="some">Here is a sample text<br /><p>A paragraph here</p></div><ul><li>List Item</li></ul>'.match(/<\w+/g)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
String input = "<div class=\"some\">Here is a sample text<br /><p>A paragraph here</p></div><ul><li>List Item</li></ul><6>";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);
String result = "";
while( (result = scanner.findInLine("<\\w+")) !=null ){
    System.out.println(result);
}
```